# Unable to install any package in Linux mint 17

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I am not able to install any software. I tried the commands like `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` after some googling. But no success till yet.

Please help me out. I will be thankful to you.

Here is error output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
blueman is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdbs dh-translations libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblzma-dev
  libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpng12-dev libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev
  libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 python-scour tcl8.5 tk8.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 209 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up iotop (0.6-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package iotop (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 Setting up python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu1) ...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
     from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
   File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
     from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
 dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
iotop
python-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Which command output you Post of? And What `sudo dpkg --configure -a` results in?

Comment: It is output of simple package install command

 "sudo apt-get install blueman". Blueman is bluetooth utility for the Linux Mint.

Comment: Does `apt-get --reinstall install libpython2.7-minimal` fix things?

Comment: No It didn't. still receiving same error

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.6-8) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 iotop

 python-setuptools

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: If you have `debsums` installed, does `sudo debsums -ca` output anything? (It may be worth installing it, if you can...) What about `which python`?

Comment: Please see the output of that command(debsums) at here, http://pasted.co/96ca10d9

whcih python returns -> /usr/bin/python